# .Net regex does not match/replcae pattern in multiline snippet

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following line:

```
 var snippet = @"Lane\rHemel Hempstead\rHP39PP\r\rPhone\r+44772930000\rEmail\rAmberlie_10371599_Wright@yahoo.co.uk\r\r\rLookin"
```

I would like to replace the phone number with a number of dots so I am doing the following:

```
snippet = Regex.Replace(snippet, @"^[^\s](\(?\+?[0-9]+\)?)?[0-9_ \-\(\)]+$", "....", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

however nothing gets replaced, my thought was that maybe this is not performing a global search but apparently .net regex is global by default.

any ideas?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: While you could try that with `RegexOptions.Multiline`, I don't think it will consider `\r` like a newline

Comment: @Avinash Id like the phone number to be replaced with "...."

Comment: only four dots? Does the phone number always exists just after to the string `phone`

Comment: @avinash what does it matter how many dots, that is not the issue here

Comment: you're missing the text where you want to find/replace in the code you provided. I mean in the `Regex.Replace`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you provide more information about your constraints? If you want to replace a number on its own line with or without a plus sign to start, and the newlines are \r only, then you can use:

```
var regexString = @"\+?[0-9]+\\r";
var targetString = @"Lane\rFoo Bar\rHP39PP\r\rPhone\r+44772930000\rEmail\rAnon_10371599_Name@example.com\r\r\rLookin";
var result = Regex.Replace(targetString, regexString, "....\\r");
```

Result:

```
Lane\rFoo Bar\rHP39PP\r\rPhone\r....\rEmail\rAnon_10371599_Name@example.com\r\r\rLookin
```

This is not very general, but it fits with the data provided. For clarity, this is simple matching as follows:

```
\+? - Escape the + sign, and make it optional
[0-9]+ - One or more digits
\\r - Escape the backslash so that we match the end of line characters '\r'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regular expression instead: `(?<=\\r)(\(?\+?[0-9]+\)?)?[0-9_ \-\(\)]+(?=\\r)`

It replaces the start/end of string symbols with a search for `\r` before and after the phone number (without including it in the result). If your line breaks are always represented by this character, then it should work for you. Otherwise, as others have mentioned, the multiline modifier is another option.

Test: [Pythex](http://pythex.org/?regex=(%3F%3C%3D%5C%5Cr)(%5C(%3F%5C%2B%3F%5B0-9%5D%2B%5C)%3F)%3F%5B0-9_%20%5C-%5C(%5C)%5D%2B(%3F%3D%5C%5Cr)&test_string=%20Lane%5CrHemel%20Hempstead%5CrHP39PP%5Cr%5CrPhone%5Cr%2B44772930000%5CrEmail%5CrAmberlie_10371599_Wright%40yahoo.co.uk%5Cr%5Cr%5CrLookin%0A&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)